# How to get a list of all valid IP addresses in a local network?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, lan, nmap

Is there a way to get a list of all valid IP addresses in a local network?

I mean all IP addresses that each user is using in the network.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/261818/how-can-i-list-all-ips-in-the-connected-network-through-terminal-preferably

Answer (score 503, accepted):

Install **nmap**,

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

then

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.*
```

or more commonly

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

will scan the entire .1 to .254 range

This does a simple ping scan in the entire subnet to see which hosts are online.

Comment: Per the man page "In newer releases of nmap, -sP is known as -sn". If the wildcard is not working, you can try something like nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24    or    nmap -sn 192.168.1.100-199

Comment: If you're using zsh, you will need to put quotes around the range to avoid file matching: nmap -sP '192.168.1.*'

Comment: Is there any chance nmap might crash or do any harm to any of the services or machines running in the subnet?

Comment: @Jin Izzraeel No chance of any harm being done. Can't say if it'll crash or not, but the chances are very slim.

Comment: nmap only finds my router. Is there a way to find all connected machines?

Comment: if your smartdevice is ON, but its screen OFF, nmap will not find it.

Comment: nice it work! can I also check more information on this specific ip address?

Comment: On Mac OSX on an Android phone hotspot the only way that found the other connected IP address was with double-verbose mode:  `nmap -sn -vv 192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this for the IP command?

Comment: @Sunil Bojanapally   thanks for the simple and working answer

Answer (score 410):

Try following steps:

1. Type `ipconfig` (or `ifconfig` on Linux) at command prompt. This will give you the IP address of your own machine. For example, your machine's IP address is 192.168.1.6. So your broadcast IP address is 192.168.1.255.
2. Ping your broadcast IP address `ping 192.168.1.255` (may require `-b` on Linux)
3. Now type `arp -a` (apt install net-tools). You will get the list of all IP addresses on your segment.

Comment: it doesn't work on my PC (windows 8)

Comment: This worked on my mac - OSX 10.10.3

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu Linux, I typed `ifconfig` instead of `ipconfig` to get this to work.

Comment: a lot of device not founded

Comment: arp -a only found my router.  nmap found all the hosts.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063] worked perfect thank you

Comment: This doesn't work on ubuntu-16.04

Comment: This answer could be improved with explanations for steps 2 and 3. What do these commands do (e.g. why do I need to ping my broadcast IP?)? What does arp do? Do I have to do step 2 before step 3? If so, why?

Comment: now we may use `ip route` instead ipconfig

Answer (score 29):

If you want to see which IP addresses are in use on a specific subnet then there are several different IP Address managers.

Try [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/) or [Solarwinds](http://www.solarwinds.com/ip-address-manager.aspx) or [Advanced IP Scanner](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com)

Comment: I used Advanced Ip scanner