# How to get the IP addresses of a device using its MAC id from inside a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, networking, ip, subnet

Is there a way to get the IP address of a device (running on my host machine) if I know its MAC address from inside a Docker Container? I have already tried all the solutions suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669585/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-valid-ip-addresses-in-a-local-network).

1) Trying to broadcast ping and using `arp -a` only gives the Gateway address, since docker is running inside a subnet.

2) Using `nmap` I cannot verify the MAC, I could only see if there is a live host in that address.

I tried the above by running docker in `--privileged` mode and still the results are the same.

Comment: how about running with `--net host`?

Comment: The container your are running. `docker run --net host .....`

Comment: Running Docker with `--net host`, solves the issue but compensates the feature of docker (which is to run isolated from host network)

Comment: I am not a networking expert but I think this may not be straightforward. See this https://superuser.com/questions/763371/arp-requesting-to-another-subnet-how and https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27869/arp-scan-different-subnet

Comment: Thanks for this.