# list all ip address of all devices connected java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I write a client-socket program and make chat between different devices

but if i wanted to connect two device on network I Establised through CMD,

so if I Create Socket and bind to it such IP and Port

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
```

i should replace the IP ( 127.0.0.1 ) to the IP of the anther machine in the network

Is there's a way to list all IPS in the network to select from it to put the IP automatically in the Sokect  ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It seems like listing all the websites you can visit from your browser. The list would be huge.

Comment: @clinomaniac is there an alternative solution ?

Comment: Your question is unclear - have you read any of the thousands of articles about basic socket programming available?

Comment: I already study Socket Programming and make an application on it

Comment: the problem is how to get the IP of anther user connected in the same network with me .. to send Packet to him with such message

Comment: Take a look at the first result on Google for [java simple client server program](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/) - it should give you some directional help.  The server is given the client address during the connection process.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You can use the approach mentioned in this post:

[How to get a list of all valid IP addresses in a local network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669585/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-valid-ip-addresses-in-a-local-network)

You can call these methods from your program using

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this solution suitable for Linux , I am using windows 10

Comment: What if this is run in a class A network?  In that case there are a bit over 16 million addresses.  How long do you think this will take to run?

Comment: @stdunbar I have mentioned that in the first comment to the question. This was to be used with caution.